# How can I add JSON data to my file upload in Web API?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, amazon-s3

I followed this guide http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-directly-upload-files-to-amazon.html and I was able to successfully upload files to Amazon S3 in my Web API Project. Happy with the results I decided to add the remaining logic which was JSON from the client.  The screen is a create user screen that also has a file uploader.  I'd like to send all the user data and uploaded file at once instead of using multiple calls.

Is this possible?  If so how should I should tweak the referenced example so it can accept both JSON and the uploaded file?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Employees/Upload")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Upload()
{
    StorageService storageService = new StorageService();

    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    InMemoryMultipartStreamProvider provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync<InMemoryMultipartStreamProvider>(new InMemoryMultipartStreamProvider());

    NameValueCollection formData = provider.FormData;
    string userName = formData["UserName"];

    IList<HttpContent> files = provider.Files;

    HttpContent file = files[0];
    Stream fileStream = await file.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    storageService.UploadFile("your bucketname", userName, fileStream);
    string preSignedUrl = storageService.GeneratePreSignedURL("your bucketname", userName, 3000);

    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { preSignedUrl });
}
```

Comment: So you want someone to read the referenced link and process the flow of the code and then answer your very general question?  Down vote!

Comment: I apologize - I thought it would help eliminate the game of fifty questions since my code is almost verbatim... I'll update my question to include the code in my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to capture form data on the POST as well as the file, though not as JSON, like other API calls.

Take a look at the form post in Fiddler.  You should see something like this on the text view tab:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary9j1TS9WuwcTWV7OX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="RecordTypeId"

120
------WebKitFormBoundary9j1TS9WuwcTWV7OX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="RecordId"

1251857
------WebKitFormBoundary9j1TS9WuwcTWV7OX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Tags"

------WebKitFormBoundary9j1TS9WuwcTWV7OX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Resource"; filename="sampleUpload1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Sample upload file 1
------WebKitFormBoundary9j1TS9WuwcTWV7OX--
```

In this example, my form has a "RecordTypeId", "RecordId" and "Tags" field on the form. So you can read that data from the "provider.FormData", just like you did with the username.

So, each piece of the data that would have been in your JSON object, would show up in the form data.

Comment: thank you for the feedback - this is what I discovered yesterday but unfortunately won't work for my scenario.  My user create screen sends a nested JSON response to the API and I was hoping I could somehow add the file attachment to it.  It looks like as of right now I'll just have to create the user, return the id and then add attachments with the correspondind user id.  It's not the end of the world, I just thought it would be nice to handle it all in one call